# Support for Type Hints PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, type-hinting

I am trying to write code with Type Hinting. However, it seems that my IDE PyCharm 2021.1 (Community Edition) does not help me. Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: Try `my_list : list[int] = []` and tell us. I didn't know that what you write was valid, but if it doesn't type well, that's not helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may type hint like this, and Pycharm will highlight `"foo"` with `Expected type 'int' (matched generic type '_T'), got 'str' instead`

```
my_list: list[int] = []
my_list.append(4)
my_list.append("foo")
```